# Does C++ support cache control instructions

Tags: c++, optimization, c++17

As a `gcc` entension [we can](http://lwn.net/Articles/255364/) `void _mm_stream_pi(__m64 *p, __m64 a);` if we want to store efficiently a large object in main memory, which will not be accessed soon. This [seems to be supported](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/03a2xda2(v=vs.100).aspx) in Windows environments as well with the exact same signature. Streaming to main memory, without invalidating the caches, is supposed to save thousand of cycles of waiting on I/O.

[Write combining](http://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.bg/2011/07/write-combining.html) is another technique for reducing main memory access, which is in the hands of the programmer. Yet checking cache line size and adjusting the code to conform to the number is a manual task.

*Are there any abstractions over these concepts, provided by the C++ standard?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, people are working on it as part of the SIMD proposal

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4184.pdf 6.2.2 non-temporal access

For write combining I don't think that C++ as language have to do something. This is an implementation detail that is not exposed to the ISA contrary to the streaming SIMD extension